# Insert failed. attachmentimg: Class.AttachmentImgController.saveImg: line 26, column 1

Tags: attachment, controller-extension, inline-visualforce

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]:
>   [Parent] Error is in expression '{!saveImg}' in component
>    in page attachmentimg:
>   Class.AttachmentImgController.saveImg: line 26, column 1

this is my class

```
public class AttachmentImgController{

    public Attachment att{get;set;}
    public contact con{get;set;}
    public String recId;
    public List<attachment> documentList{get;set;}

    public AttachmentImgController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        documentList=new List<attachment>();
        con = (contact)sc.getRecord();
        recId = sc.getId();

        att=new Attachment();

    }
     public String getFileId() {
        String fileId;
        List<Attachment> attachedFiles = [select Id from Attachment where parentId =:recId];
        if( attachedFiles != null && attachedFiles.size() > 0 ) {
            fileId = attachedFiles[0].Id;
        }
        return fileId;    
    }
    public void saveImg(){
        att.parentId = con.id;
        insert att;

    }
}
```

this is my page

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" extensions="AttachmentImgController" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                 <apex:inputFile value="{!att.body}" fileName="{!att.name}"/>
                <apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!FileId}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save Image/File" action="{!saveImg}" />
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: The problem probably is that you are trying to save an attachment for a contact that hasn't been inserted yet.

Comment: Vipin Are you passing Contact Id in url?

Comment: no i am not passing contact id in url

Comment: @VipinIndora you need to pass Contact Id like `https://ap1.salesforce.com/apex/VFPageName?Id=003aaasdgf22hnb`

Comment: this page work on inline vfpage of contact and image uploaded and show.i want to attachment of pdf and excel also what should i do to check contains type

Comment: @VipinIndora you may need to use `ContentType` field in attachment

Comment: @VipinIndora is your above `required field` issue  solved?

Comment: How to use ContentType, i want to upload either jpg or pdf at a time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34542/discussion-between-ratan-and-vipin-indora).

Comment: @VipinIndora you may need to use like `<apex:inputFile id="addFile" accept="pdf,jpeg" />`